# Function escaping quote is not working correctly

Tags: php, mysql, escaping, stripslashes, magic-quotes

I'm trying to figure out why this function does not work correctly.

It's adding an extra `\` every time I edit my entries.

Online server has these settings:

```
magic_quotes_gpc On 
magic_quotes_runtime Off 
magic_quotes_sybase Off
```

Here is the code:

```
function esc($s)
{
  if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    if (ini_get('magic_quotes_sybase'))
      $s = str_replace("''", "'", $s);
    else
      $s = stripslashes($s);
  } //if 
  return mysql_real_escape_string($s);
}
```

**Edit note:**

I have tried completely removing this function to see what it does... and it does the same thing, so I have realized that `addslashes` is also use in the code for the same thing.

The extra `\` were there because `magic_quote` was `ON`

Comment: Do you mean you're getting extra back slashes e.g.

"Your function\\'s return string looks like this"

Comment: yes it's add one \ every save

Comment: @Dukeling please stop that. magic quotes is a more genaralized term than magic quotes gpc. Just add a synonym, if you want to participate that much.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Yeah, I realize now that most of the [tag:magic-quotes] questions are actually about PHP. I can't suggest a synonym as I don't have 5 reputation for the tag. [Related Meta discussion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203973/quote-tags-cleanup).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I have fixed the problem. A quick solution for now, I have removed `function esc($s)`.
I changed `Magic_Quote` to OFF in php.ini.
I'm keeping addslashes solution.

Answer (score 2):

Your function makes little sense. If magic quotes is on (eg. input is escaped), you unescape it. If it's not on, you escape it. So you'll get different results, depending on if you have magic quote on or not.

In any case, relying on magic quotes is a really bad practice. You should:

1. [Disable magic quotes or reverse its effect globally](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php).
2. *Either* [escape strings](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) when you construct SQL queries *or* (better) [use prepared statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php).
3. *Not* unescape/strip/whatever anything when you get it back from the database.

Comment: is this possible to use escape string even if magic_quotes_gpc is On?

Comment: What do you mean by "use escape string"?

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to stripslashes even if magic_quotes_sybase is on:

```
function esc($s)
{
    if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
        if (ini_get('magic_quotes_sybase'))
            $s = str_replace("''", "'", $s);
        
        $s = stripslashes($s);
    } //if 
    return mysql_real_escape_string($s);
}
```

You might also want to take a look at PHP's [get_magic_quotes_gpc](https://www.php.net/get_magic_quotes_gpc) function page, there are several user comments on the page with fairly elegant solutions for ensuring slashes are stripped.

Comment: I have tryed your code without the else and I still get same issue.

Comment: The issue being that you get too many slashes?  Are you sure extra slashes aren't be added prior to the string being sent to the function?  Only one set of slashes would be removed by the stripslashes function.